# Cannot import Numpy with Anaconda3 Distrobution

Tags: python, windows, numpy, anaconda

When I write a script to import numpy, eg

```
import numpy as np
```

and attempt to run it in from a Windows command prompt (or just double-click the script) with the version of Python distributed with Anaconda3 2018.12 (3.7.1) I receive the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line
 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recipe.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142,
 in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 1
3, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line
8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", lin
e 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line
 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've done a little research that suggests that this was a problem the Anaconda3 installation for Python 3.6.0, but I haven't seen anything about the version I'm running now.  Has anyone had a similar problem and know a fix?

Comment: Are you useing Windows ? How to your proceed ? Are you using a CMM prompt or an Anaconda prompt to run your code ? (Anaconda prompt is recommended until now). What is the conda version that you have ? (type "conda list" and you will see the full list of packages and their version). Did you create a env or your use the base ?

Comment: So your questions got me to the answer.  I just reinstalled anaconda3, selecting 'add Anaconda to your path' and it worked fine, thus suggesting it was an issue with how I had set up my path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the way I had set up my path.  I'm not certain what I had done wrong, but selecting 'add Anaconda to my Path environmental variable' during installation fixed the issue.